# Regex for matching multilingual numbers not detecting Chinese numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have a method which detects whether a String is a number:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String num)
{
    return num.matches("(\\p{N})+");
}
```

The above method is successfully matching English, Hindi, Arabic numbers but fails to match Chinese numbers:

三十萬零二百五十 etc.

Is it possible to create a regex which can match a number from any language(or major languages)?

edit: the number won't be a decimal, it will be used to validate a phone number.

Comment: These look like belonging to `\p{Lo}` category.

Comment: @stribizhev it's working, but the definition of \p{Lo} from http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html seems to be saying that it might match characters other than numbers?

Comment: Is there any (easily automatable) way to tell if this characters are used as digits? Can they be used as non-numeric part of words/text?

Comment: No idea, the only solution that I can think of is just add them all into the character class. Like `"(?U)[\\p{N}一二三四五六七八九十百千万萬億亿兆零]+"`.

Comment: @stribizhev but this solution would only be able to help support Chinese, how will i be able to do this for all the unsupported languages?
do you know of any character which falls under \\p{Lo} but isn't a number?

Comment: No, I am afraid that is something I cannot be sure of.

Comment: @stribizhev ok, thank you very much for your support :)

Comment: I don't know anything on chinese characters, but are you sure these characters `三十萬零二百五十` are numbers and not literals like `one two three ...`

Comment: @Toto i also don't know Chinese :), but i referred dozens of links, some of them being:

http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chinese_%28Mandarin%29/Numbers

Comment: I've just tried google traduction from english to chinese, for `1` it gives `1`, for `one` it gives `一` same for `3` => `3` and `three` => `三`

Comment: @Toto yes i have already tried that too, google can't always be right ;)

Comment: Sure :) ; waiting for a chinese people that can answer.

Comment: If that is only a Chinese issue, you can use the approach I suggested. Also, here is [a nice resource on Chinese numbers](http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html). Acc. to that page, the Chinese numbers can be matched with `[\\p{N}零一二三四五六七八九十百千萬億万亿壹貳叄肆伍陸柒捌玖拾佰仟贰叁陆]`.

Comment: @SarthakMittal can you give more examples? I have written solution below and I want to text it

Comment: Since when Chinese use Chinese characters for there phone numbers instead of typing arabic numbers? Did you ever write **your** phone number as a word like "onemilliontwohundredthirtyfourthousandfivehundredsixtyseven"? Doesn't make sense at all. Why should Chinese do so?

Comment: `三十萬零二百五十` is normally written as `三十萬零二百五`. By the way: `二百五` (250) means "idiot" in Chinese language.

Answer (score 1):

If you try with javascript it will work with This regex Pattern

```js
const stringNumber = "三十萬零二百五十12";
const regex = /\d+/g; 

const numbers = stringNumber.match(regex);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: This is returning ['12'] for me and not including the Chinese numbers.

Answer (score 0):

as some have already pointed out in the comments, these are the words used for numbers, i.e. "one", "two", "three" etc.
China introduced the indo-arabic numbers in the 19th century, so `\p{N}` should also match Chinese numbers. If you also want the literals, you should include them, as stribizhev suggested.