# How to convert chinese number to english?

Tags: javascript, locale

I have an array of objects which contain different periods. I want to extract each object that includes a number. The array looks like this:

```js
[
{id: 1, label: "Last 30 days"},
{id: 2, label: "Yesterday"}
]
```

I've managed to do it with the following function:

```js
allPeriods.filter(period => !period.label.split(" ").some(p => Number(p)))
```

However, this can't work if I receive Chinese numbers. Number("四") will indeed return NaN. I've checked the toLocaleString("en-IN") method, but it doesn't change anything. How to fix this?

Comment: In JavaScript, the thing you mentioned is a character not a number. You may need a dictionary and map them accordingly.

Comment: I don't know enough about Chinese to answer confidently but I bet a regular expression [like `^[\d零一二三四五六七八九十百千萬億万亿壹貳叄肆伍陸柒捌玖拾佰仟贰叁陆]+$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523130/regex-for-matching-multilingual-numbers-not-detecting-chinese-numbers#comment52907493_32523130) would be a good start

Comment: Unfortunately, `Intl.NumberFormat` only is a formatter and doesn't (yet) have a `parse` method...